# Write down the matrix that belongs T in the standard basis of R^3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let be $T: \mathbb R^3$ a linear transformations which transforms  $\vec i$ into  $\vec j$, vector $\vec j$ into $\vec i$ + $\vec j$ and 2*$\vec k$ into 4* $\vec i$. Write down the matrix that belongs T in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$ .

My notes show me that I have to write down the columns are  $\vec i$,  $\vec j$, and 2*  $\vec k$, and rows as the three standard vectors  $\vec i$,  $\vec j$ and  $\vec k$. When filling up the coresponding matrix I get the result

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 4 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ That is apparently wrong but I don't know why. I am using as a template assignments like tranformation from $T(\vec a) = \vec a - \vec b$  which gives me the vector
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & x \\
-1 & x & x \\
0 & x & x \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

($x \rightarrow b-c$ and $c-a$ in corresponding columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T(2\vec k)=4\vec i$, then $T(\vec k)=2\vec i$ and therefore your matrix should be$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&2\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: So this is the solution, regardless if we take the template into the account?

Comment: I don't know what your template says, but, yes, this is the solution.

Comment: Right afterthe first matrix

Comment: I do not understand what is written there. It is not that I think it is wrong. I simply do not know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Recall $\vec{i}=(1,0,0)$, $\vec{j}=(0,1,0)$ and $\vec{k}=(0,0,1)$. Then $$\left\{\begin{aligned}&T(\vec{i})=\vec{j}\\&T(\vec{j})=\vec{i}+\vec{j}\\&T(2\vec{k})=4\vec{i}\end{aligned}\right.\iff
\left\{\begin{aligned}&T(1,0,0)=\color{green}{(0,1,0)}\\&T(0,1,0)=(1,0,0)+(0,1,0)=\color{green}{(1,1,0)}\\&T(2(0,0,1))\underset{\text{linearity}}{=}2T(0,0,1)=4(1,0,0)\to T(0,0,1)=\color{red}{(2,0,0)}\end{aligned}\right.$$ Thus the matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&\color{red}2\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$